# Exactly where to fetch data inside a sevice (ngOnInit or inside constructor)?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, firebase-authentication

On logOut from my ionic angular app I am using auth.signOut() metohd. But when I register with new email, in home component it is fetching data from previously signedOut user. It looks like constructor of service is not getting called. When I reload, it works fine.

```
constructor(
private authService: AuthService,
private db: AngularFireDatabase,
) {
this.getUserId();
this.patientsRef = db.list(`/${this.loggedUserId}/patients`);
this.afPatients = this.patientsRef.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({ id: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))
        )
    );
} 

getUserId() {
this.authSub = this.authService.userId
.pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(userId => {
  if (!userId) {
    return;
  } else {
    this.loggedUserId = userId.toString();
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current code

Comment: I am not sure what code to show. I have multiple services to fetch userdata  from firebase. In each service's constructor I am getting currently logged userId and then I am fetching data of that user. But when I logOut and again signIn with different user, it seems constructor is not getting called. How to rectify this?

Answer (score -1):

You can call unsubscribe inside the `auth.signOut()`. Also it would be better if you provided sample code.